# SwingWorker Thread doesn't stop action in background

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, concurrency, swingworker

My SwingWorker doesn't stop the background thread from executing when I call .cancel(true); I've tried loads of different things - running the background process on it's own thread, calling the method directly, surrounding the method/process in try catch to force the process to jump out of the for loop and so on....for some reason the process just continues. Basically, there is JButton that when clicked starts the SwingWorker and background process, and when I click that button again, I want the process to stop. There is a fair bit of code, The GUI (PlayAKnit), the method/process which is part of my KnitGraph class and a SoundPlayer object which loops sounds. I will share what I can here:

**code in GUI class**

```
   button.addActionListener(e -> {
        KnitGraph test = new KnitGraph(new KnitSpeakIn("CherryStitch").getKnitFile());
        Thread graph = new Thread(test);
        SwingWorker startWorker = new SwingWorker() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                   
                    test.parseCommands(0, test.getCommands().length);
                return null;
            }
        };
        if (button.getText().equals("KNIT")) {
          
            button.setText("UNPICK");
            button.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 48));
            startWorker.execute();

 
        }
        else {
            startWorker.cancel(true);
            button.setText("KNIT");
            button.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 72));
        }
    });
```

**method that runs in background calls methods that make sounds**

void parseCommands(int start, int end) throws InterruptedException {

```
    int asterixStartLocation = 0;
    int asterixEndLocation = 0;

    for(int i = start; i<end;i++) {
        System.out.println(commands[i]);
        if (commands[i].contains("co")) {
            System.out.println("casting on");
            castOn(extractInt(commands[i]));
        }
        if (commands[i].contains("*")) {
            if (!asterixFound) {
                System.out.println("I found an asterix");
                asterixFound = true;
                commands[i] = commands[i].replace('*', ' ');
                asterixStartLocation = i;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("I found another asterix!");
                asterixFound = false;
                asterixEndLocation = i;
                commands[i] = commands[i].replace('*', ' ');
                parseCommands(i, i+1);
                parseCommands(asterixStartLocation, asterixEndLocation);
            }
        }
        if (commands[i].matches("\\spurl|\\sknit|\\sPurl|\\sKnit")) {
            for (int j = 0; j < stitchesInRowBelow; j++) {
                knitOrPurl();
            }
        }
        if (commands[i].contains("tog") || commands[i].contains("ssk")) {
            if (commands[i].contains("ssk")) {
                int count = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < commands[i].length(); k++) {
                    if ((commands[i]).charAt(k) == 's') {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                decrease(count - 1);
            }
            else if (commands[i].contains("psso")) {
                decrease(2);
            }else {
                decrease(extractInt(commands[i])-1);
            }
        }
        if (commands[i].contains("yo")) {
            yarnOver();
        }
        if (commands[i].contains("kfb")) {
            increase();
        }
        if (commands[i].matches("\\sk\\d|\\sp\\d|\\sk\\d\\stbl|\\sp\\d\\stbl|\\s*k\\d|\\s*p\\d")) {
            int noOfStitches = extractInt(commands[i]);
            for (int n=0;n<noOfStitches;n++) {
                knitOrPurl();
            }
        }
        if (commands[i].contains("cast off")) {
            castOff();
        }
    }
}
```

**method in SoundPlayer class just loops random .wav files**

```
public void run() {
    File sound = new File(sounds[randomInt]);
    try {
        String url = sound.toURI().toURL().toString();
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new URL(url)));
      
        clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
       

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Hmmm... the [Javadoc for `SwingWorker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) doesn't seem to say _anything_ about what `cancel()` does. That's not encouraging. I notice though that there's one thing missing from your list of stuff you've tried. Have you tried checking `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` in your `parseCommands()` loop?

Comment: Thank you for your response! I’ve actually fixed this now: the problem was that I had created my worker threads inside my action listener, so each time the action listener was created, the previous reference to the worker thread was lost, and so calling .cancel effectively did nothing. I moved the worker threads outside of the action listener, and now it works!! I’m VERY happy lol